# Implementing Barcode Scanner in form fields

Tags: javascript

I am facing one issue regarding barcode scanner.

I have multiple fields in my form, all fields should be editable. But when I am scanning via scanner then that code is printing in all the fields of form. If I apply preventDefault then other fields will also not work.

How can I achieve it.
I am using jQuery-Scanner-Detection .

Comment: Any start event is there for scanner?

Comment: How about sharing some code, maybe a [mcve]